# Как в gino удалить первую запись в таблице?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, gino

У меня есть таблица Info, при достижении определенного количества записей, я хочу удалять самую первую запись.

Таблица:

```py
class Info(TimedBaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'information'
    id = Column(BigInteger)
    info = Column(String(200))

    query: sql.Select
```

Можно ли как-то переделать этот код, чтобы он удалял только первый элемент? Он полностью очищает всю таблицу:

```py
await Info.delete.where(message.from_user.id == Info.id).gino.status()
```

Answer (score 1):

Вроде так.

```
info = await Info.query.gino.first()
await info.delete()
```